# What happens when powershell script encounters EOF while a quote is open?

Tags: powershell

Unicorn.py generates a string that looks like

`powershell -flag1 -flag2 "something " obfuscation; powershell "more gibbrish`

Interestingly, if this command is saved in a file `filename.txt` Windows executes it before opening the file in notepad.txt (by which time the file is empty).

Why is the file executed despite the extension?
What does the script do when it encounters EOF after odd number of quotation marks?

---

Edited:
Unicorn (https://github.com/trustedsec/unicorn)  is a script that "enables privilege elevation and arbitrary code execution". If you know what it means. Of course I did NOT put the actual string, just the key features.

Comment: I just tried putting that content in a text file named `filename.txt` and then opening it in Notepad, and Windows not only did not execute it as a Powershell script, but it also did not empty the file content before it was opened in Notepad. How do we reproduce this issue?

Comment: If a .txt file is executed before being opened in Notepad I would consider that an indicator of the system being compromised (or at least severe misconfiguration). You may want to investigate that.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers  This question is about a  "Compromising script", created by Unicorn.py

Comment: @KenWhite I am glad I didn't put the actual string produced by the `Unicorn.py` because you would get infected. This is the reason I said "looks like" as opposed to "is". String in the question captures key features of the delivery vector, but it is not a verbatim copy.

Comment: This file is passed as a parameter.

Comment: @sixtytrees What OP is describing doesn't make any sense.  There is no "tricked execution" of a text file.  PowerShell's parser will strip the quote and parse the command as normal as that indicates to PowerShell it's being sent `-Command` and not `-File`.

Comment: Could you please describe exactly what you mean by "opening the file in notepad.txt"? For example, did you double-click that file to open it, and if yes, did you do this in Windows File Explorer? Did you use some command line to open the file in Notepad? Did you use Notepad's File -> Open menu to open the file? How did you open it *exactly*?

Answer (score 1):

Purely out of IT security interest.

I think that if you read the manual in unicorn.py, at absolutely no time does it say that the script should be left in the txt file.

The PowerShell script is written inside the txt file and called the "payload" (very hacker like). What is left for you is always how to execute this code on the victim's computer.

The manual proposes Word code injection, simply executing the PowerShell in cmd (I quote "Next simply copy the powershell command to something you have the ability for remote command execution."), Excel Auto_Open attack, and so on.

If reading the manual is too much there is always a [video](https://n0where.net/powershell-downgrade-attack-unicorn). The only time the "hacker" uses a notepad like is on his linux operated system (how ironic)… I watched it because I love this Papa Roach music Last Resort...

For those who are concerned about IT security I recommend this article [dosfuscation](https://www.fireeye.com/content/dam/fireeye-www/blog/pdfs/dosfuscation-report.pdf). This is really instructive about how you have to be extra careful when receiving mails, outside document,... and how humanity can waste so much time spying, deceiving, inventing new twisted strategies... Aren't we great !

Windows like any other system has many system flaw but opening notepad is not one of them. Unless your notepad has been replaced by a hacker using unicorn…

Answer (score 0):

There is an even number of brackets in the obfuscated script. Did you mix up `''` with `"`?

Empty txt file means that you've sent the attack.txt over network to a drive accessible by updated antivirus and antivirus quarantined/deleted file contents. Since you didn't know about this interaction with antivirus your environment is NOT secure. Which means you might have other malware from previous test lurking on your "clean" network.